# Eager-Future2 Library :Parallel Programming in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am using **Fedora 19** SBCL. I'm trying to install [eager-future2](http://common-lisp.net/project/eager-future/).
I've downloaded the source, but I can't figure out how to install it. I tried

```
(asdf:load-system 'eager-future)
```

and I even tried **load**ing individual .lisp files in the source, but whenever I try to use the **pcall** function, I get an error, "undefined function PCALL".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/), which works with a number of Common Lisp implementations,  you can install this pretty easily.  Then, the **pcall** function is defined in the **eager-future2** package, so you'll need to write the package prefix, e.g., **eager-future2:pcall**, or **use** the package in your own package.  Using [**apropos**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apropo.htm) is a good way to find out what symbols exist. Thus, I was able to do this:

```
CL-USER> (quicklisp:quickload "EAGER-FUTURE2")
;=> ("EAGER-FUTURE2")

CL-USER> (apropos "PCALL")
; EAGER-FUTURE2:PCALL (fbound)
; No value

CL-USER> (eager-future2:pcall (lambda () (print 'hello-world)))
;=> #<EAGER-FUTURE2:FUTURE {10059C8713}>
```

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *f* (eager-future2:pcall (lambda () (print 'hello))))
;=> *F*
CL-USER> *f*
;=> #<EAGER-FUTURE2:FUTURE {1005F4AD93}>
CL-USER> (eager-future2:ready-to-yield? *f*)
;=> T
CL-USER> (eager-future2:yield *f*)
;=> HELLO
```

Comment: Parallel Fibonacci Program: (defun fib (n)
  (if (> n 2)
      (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))
      1))


(print "Fibonacci fo 7 with serial execution")
(time (fib 7))

(print "Fibonacci fo 7 with parallel execution")
(time (let ((f1 (pexec (fib 6)))
            (f2 (pexec (fib 5))))
        (+ (yield f1) (yield f2))))

Comment: @user2201980 I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  I see some code (but it's next to impossible to read code in comments), but you haven't said anything *about* it.  Did it work?  Not work?  Crash? What?

Comment: Unable to format my code in previous comment. Parallel programming using eager-future3 has worked. It calculates fibonacci series (fin 7) in parallel by creating two threads ( fib 6) and (fib 5)..