# want a simple program illustrating the use of concurrent lisp using threads

Tags: concurrency, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

- I am just getting curious  about **lisp** programming and wanted to
  know how to use concurrent lisp by making threads.

  -I also wanted to be clear with the **pcall()** function in lisp.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which lisp and libraries you are using, and what is unclear to you?

Comment: @samuel-edwin-ward am using the sbcl lisp on fedora 19.I was reading the threading part in the sbcl manual,and just wanted a simple program that would illustrate the use of threading in it.Also i noticed the ex in which pcall  was used to automatically perform the operation concurrently.Ex (pcall (+(* a b) (*c d))

Comment: This is almost certainly off topic (too broad, not enough detail, etc.), but you may find [Eager-Future2 Library :Parallel Programming in Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27798351/1281433) helpful, at least in terms of links to follow.

Comment: Ok that definately helped me.Thank You Joshua Taylor

Answer (score 2):

the comments to your question give you the right key to solve the problem. I hope this is still helpful.

If you want to use concurrency with common lisp, One of the ways is Eager Future2 http://common-lisp.net/project/eager-future/, but you can choose other models here http://www.cliki.net/concurrency.

Eager Future is based, like the name suggested, in Futures

"Eager Future2 is a Common Lisp library that provides composable
concurrency primitives that unify parallel and lazy evaluation, are
integrated with CL's condition system, and have automatic resource
management.
The basic unit of concurrency in Eager Future2 is the future, which is
a data type that acts as a proxy for the values of a no-argument
function (thunk) that is computed concurrently."

Let's see how works pcall, from documentation of Eager Furture2 we find:

"
function pcall (thunk &optional (future-type *default-future-type*)) => future
Given a function of no arguments, returns an object (called a
future) that can later be used to retrieve the values computed by the
function.
future-type (by default the value of *default-future-type*) can either
be :eager, :speculative, or :lazy. See the documentation of
*default-future-type* for an explanation of the different future
types.
The function is called in an unspecified dynamic environment."

sample lisp code

```
;; use quicklisp to add Eager-Future2 to your common lisp
;; implementation in my case I use GVIM, SLIMV and SBCL
(quicklisp:quickload "EAGER-FUTURE2")

(defparameter *future* (eager-future2:pcall #'compute))

*future*

;; Returns non nil if the future values have been computed, nil otherwise
(eager-future2:ready-to-yield? *future*)

;;Returns the computed values, see delayed future, computes the value in current thread, 
;;and speculative future computes the future in a current thread if not is evalatuated 
;;in another thread. 
(eager-future2:yield *future*)




;; function for the long computation, from http://www.cliki.net/fibonacci
(defun fib (n) 
  "Tail-recursive computation of the nth element of the Fibonacci sequence" 
  (check-type n (integer 0 *)) 
  (labels ((fib-aux (n f1 f2) 
             (if (zerop n) 
               f1 (fib-aux (1- n) f2 (+ f1 f2))))) 
    (fib-aux n 0 1)))

;; function with no arguments for pcall that computes fibonacci 10000th number
(defun compute () 
  (fib 10000))
```

Use in REPL

```
SBCL 1.2.4-1.fc21  Port: 4005  Pid: 1188
; SWANK 2014-10-10
CL-USER> (quicklisp:quickload "EAGER-FUTURE2")
To load "eager-future2":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    alexandria
  Install 3 Quicklisp releases:
    bordeaux-threads eager-future2 trivial-garbage
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/trivial-garbage/2013-03-12/trivial-garbage-20130312-git.tgz">
; 8.00KB
==================================================
8,197 bytes in 0.01 seconds (1143.55KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/bordeaux-threads/2013-06-15/bordeaux-threads-0.8.3.tgz">
; 18.31KB
==================================================
18,754 bytes in 0.06 seconds (327.04KB/sec)
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/eager-future2/2011-03-20/eager-future2-0.2.tgz">
; 17.34KB
==================================================
17,758 bytes in 0.07 seconds (262.75KB/sec)
; Loading "eager-future2"
[package bordeaux-threads]........................
[package trivial-garbage].........................
[package eager-future2]..
("EAGER-FUTURE2")
CL-USER> (defun fib (n) 
  "Tail-recursive computation of the nth element of the Fibonacci sequence" 
  (check-type n (integer 0 *)) 
  (labels ((fib-aux (n f1 f2)  ...))))
FIB
CL-USER> (fib 1000)
43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
CL-USER> (fib 10000)
33644764876431783266621612005107543310302148460680063906564769974680081442166662368155595513633734025582065332680836159373734790483865268263040892463056431887354544369559827491606602099884183933864652731300088830269235673613135117579297437854413752130520504347701602264758318906527890855154366159582987279682987510631200575428783453215515103870818298969791613127856265033195487140214287532698187962046936097879900350962302291026368131493195275630227837628441540360584402572114334961180023091208287046088923962328835461505776583271252546093591128203925285393434620904245248929403901706233888991085841065183173360437470737908552631764325733993712871937587746897479926305837065742830161637408969178426378624212835258112820516370298089332099905707920064367426202389783111470054074998459250360633560933883831923386783056136435351892133279732908133732642652633989763922723407882928177953580570993691049175470808931841056146322338217465637321248226383092103297701648054726243842374862411453093812206564914032751086643394517512161526545361333111314042436854805106765843493523836959653428071768775328348234345557366719731392746273629108210679280784718035329131176778924659089938635459327894523777674406192240337638674004021330343297496902028328145933418826817683893072003634795623117103101291953169794607632737589253530772552375943788434504067715555779056450443016640119462580972216729758615026968443146952034614932291105970676243268515992834709891284706740862008587135016260312071903172086094081298321581077282076353186624611278245537208532365305775956430072517744315051539600905168603220349163222640885248852433158051534849622434848299380905070483482449327453732624567755879089187190803662058009594743150052402532709746995318770724376825907419939632265984147498193609285223945039707165443156421328157688908058783183404917434556270520223564846495196112460268313970975069382648706613264507665074611512677522748621598642530711298441182622661057163515069260029861704945425047491378115154139941550671256271197133252763631939606902895650288268608362241082050562430701794976171121233066073310059947366875
CL-USER> (defun compute () 
  (fib 10000))
COMPUTE
CL-USER> (defparameter *future* (eager-future2:pcall #'compute))
*FUTURE*
CL-USER> *future*
#<EAGER-FUTURE2:FUTURE {1004F20383}>
CL-USER> (eager-future2:ready-to-yield? *future*)
T
CL-USER> (eager-future2:yield *future*)
33644764876431783266621612005107543310302148460680063906564769974680081442166662368155595513633734025582065332680836159373734790483865268263040892463056431887354544369559827491606602099884183933864652731300088830269235673613135117579297437854413752130520504347701602264758318906527890855154366159582987279682987510631200575428783453215515103870818298969791613127856265033195487140214287532698187962046936097879900350962302291026368131493195275630227837628441540360584402572114334961180023091208287046088923962328835461505776583271252546093591128203925285393434620904245248929403901706233888991085841065183173360437470737908552631764325733993712871937587746897479926305837065742830161637408969178426378624212835258112820516370298089332099905707920064367426202389783111470054074998459250360633560933883831923386783056136435351892133279732908133732642652633989763922723407882928177953580570993691049175470808931841056146322338217465637321248226383092103297701648054726243842374862411453093812206564914032751086643394517512161526545361333111314042436854805106765843493523836959653428071768775328348234345557366719731392746273629108210679280784718035329131176778924659089938635459327894523777674406192240337638674004021330343297496902028328145933418826817683893072003634795623117103101291953169794607632737589253530772552375943788434504067715555779056450443016640119462580972216729758615026968443146952034614932291105970676243268515992834709891284706740862008587135016260312071903172086094081298321581077282076353186624611278245537208532365305775956430072517744315051539600905168603220349163222640885248852433158051534849622434848299380905070483482449327453732624567755879089187190803662058009594743150052402532709746995318770724376825907419939632265984147498193609285223945039707165443156421328157688908058783183404917434556270520223564846495196112460268313970975069382648706613264507665074611512677522748621598642530711298441182622661057163515069260029861704945425047491378115154139941550671256271197133252763631939606902895650288268608362241082050562430701794976171121233066073310059947366875
CL-USER>
```

I hope that this will be usefull